React Native Expo Router - initialRouteName seems to have no effect on which screen gets rendered first
I am using Expo Router v3 with React Native 0.74 and I am trying to define an initial route name to move users to an onboarding screen if it is their first time loading the app. However, the screen that gets loaded first appears to be random. It seems that initialRouteName has no effect.
Here is what my approach looks like:
export default function RootLayout() {

  const [appReady, setAppReady] = useState(false);
  const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = useState<boolean | null>(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkFirstLaunch = async () => {
      try {
        const firstLaunch = await AsyncStorage.getItem("isFirstLaunch");
        if (firstLaunch === null) {
          await AsyncStorage.setItem("isFirstLaunch", "false");

          setFirstLoad(true);
        } else {
          setFirstLoad(false);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      } finally {
        setAppReady(true);
      }
    };
    checkFirstLaunch();
  }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
    if (loaded && appReady) {
      SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [loaded, appReady]);

  if (!loaded || !appReady || firstLoad === null) {
    return null;
  }

 return (
    <Stack initialRouteName={firstLoad ? "onboarding" : "(tabs)"}>
      <Stack.Screen name="(tabs)" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
      <Stack.Screen name="onboarding" options={{ headerShown: false }} />
    </Stack>
  );


I expect it to load the onboarding screen when it is the first render. But it sometimes does -sometimes it doesn't - even if I hardcode firstLoad to be true.

I think the problem is state updates in the 'useEffect'. You are updating states inside the useEffect which will cause another render after the first render with the updated states which means setFirstLoad will be false in the second render and the initialRouteName will be set to "(tabs)". So you need to avoid updating state inside the useEffect.
Maybe you can try using useRef instead of useState to store 'firstLoad'. Here is an example. The blue box will be shown on the first render only->
https://snack.expo.dev/FyXYRh9syuoqvDExlls1y
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
export default function RootLayout() {
  const fLoad = useRef(true);

  const [appReady, setAppReady] = useState(false);
  const [firstLoad, setFirstLoad] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    try {
      fLoad.current = false;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }

    console.log(fLoad);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        {fLoad.current ? (
          <View
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 200,
              backgroundColor: 'blue',
            }}>
            {' '}
          </View>
        ) : null}
        <Text>{fLoad.current.toString()} </Text>
        <button
          name="hi"
          onClick={() => setFirstLoad(firstLoad ? false : true)}>
          {' '}
          hi
        </button>
      </View>
    </>
  );
}

